# Unit Testing - Ignore culture when binding assembly

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, mstest

I'm very new to unit testing in C#. I added a test project with Visual Studio, but when I try to run tests, they fail, complaining about assembly binding failures.

So I enabled logging and noticed that the tests are trying to load my DLLs from a culture-specific directory (one that doesn't exist).

E.g. if the test project's DLL exists in **C:\MyProject\**, it looks for the assembly under test in **C:\MyProject\en-GB\**.

The only reference anywhere to `en-GB` is the assembly culture attribute of the assembly under test. If I change that attribute's value to say, `en-US`, the unit test binder searches for the DLL in `/en-US/`

Can I somehow specify that I do not want this behaviour?

Comment: this doesn't sound like standard behavior.  i assume you're testing an assembly that has third party dependencies. off the top of my head i know fluentvalidation has localization folder dependencies, if you are by chance using that.  if you are, just instally the nuget package into your test and you're good to go.

Comment: also, what unit testing framework?

Comment: @nathangonzalez Nope - this is all my own code. The output directories are non-standard though (i.e. so they aren't mixed with source). Framework is just whatever you get when you add a test project in VS - MSTest?

Comment: yep, thats mstest.  so when you look in the build folder your real project assemblies, not the test assembly, is there an en-GB folder?

Comment: @nathangonzalez No, nothing. The only reference anywhere to en-GB is the assembly culture attribute of the assembly under test. If I change that attribute's value to say, en-US, the unit test binder searches for the DLL in /en-US/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the documentation,

> The attribute is used by compilers to distinguish between a main assembly and a satellite assembly. A main assembly contains code and the neutral culture's resources. A satellite assembly contains only resources for a particular culture, as in [assembly:AssemblyCultureAttribute("de")]. Putting this attribute on an assembly and using something other than the empty string ("") for the culture name will make this assembly look like a satellite assembly, rather than a main assembly that contains executable code. Labeling a traditional code library with this attribute will break it, because no other code will be able to find the library's entry points at runtime.

so basically, don't use that attribute.  are you actually testing a localized satellite assembly?

Comment: No, I'm not. That's really interesting - didn't know that. Thanks for your investigative work. :)